# $ab+bc+ca=3$ and prove $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+3}}\ge \frac{9}{a+b+c+3}.$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3.$ Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+3}}\ge \frac{9}{a+b+c+3}.$$
It is Nguyen Van Quy's inequality. I tried a lot without success.

A big trouble here is the occuring equality around $(0,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}.$

After homogenizing, we will prove $$\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{c+b}+\sqrt{a+c}\ge \frac{9\sqrt{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}{a+b+c+3\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}.$$I still stuck here. Hope to see brighter ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the [HM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities) could help? Just a guess.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h455484p2559802

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Ba%5E2%2B3%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bb%5E2%2B3%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bc%5E2%2B3%7D%7D%5Cge%5Cfrac%7B9%7D%7Ba%2Bb%2Bc%2B3%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24ab%2Bbc%2Bca%3D3%24&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [ab+bc+ca=3 !](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h455484p2559802), which is a bit weaker in that it requires $a$, $b$ and $c$ to all be positive, but it contains several methods.

Answer (score 0):

By Holder $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+3}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)(2a+5b+5c)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)(2a+5b+5c)^3}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a+5b+5c)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)(2a+5b+5c)^3}}=\sqrt{\frac{1728(a+b+c)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)(2a+5b+5c)^3}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$64(a+b+c)^3\left(a+b+c+\sqrt{3(ab+ac+bc)}\right)^2\geq3\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)(2a+5b+5c)^3,$$ which we can kill by $uvw$.

About $uvw$ see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: @Ha Diep Xuan Why did you delete my solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737948 ?

Comment: Fogive me @Michael Rozenberg. My teacher said me it was for a competition. He asked my delete the topic. I am very sorry you. Hope it won't make you sad. I will consider carefully in next topics and won't let the similar troubles happen again.

Comment: I am very appreciate your help.

Comment: @Ha Diep Xuan This problem can't be used in any competition because it's a Can's problem from 2010. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h349586 I think, now you can restore my solution. Do it!

Comment: Could you tell my how to restore ? I aksed again and you post solution, right ?